# Greatest common divisor of three numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So there is gcd for two numbers, which i know how do define.

```
gcd a 0 = a

gcd a b = gcd b (a `mod` b)

gcd a b c = gcd3
```

How could i define a gcd3 for finding the greatest divisor for three numbers. The definition of gcd3 is:

```
gcd3 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
```

Comment: You can use the identity `gcd(a, b, c) = gcd(gcd(a, b), c)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take the `gcd` of three numbers the same way you take the sum of three numbers: by doing it two at a time.

```
gcd3 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
gcd3 x y z = (x `gcd` y) `gcd` z
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a smart approach. I was trying to do it based on two numbers one

Answer (score 7):

You can use `foldr1` for any count of numbers as:

```haskel
gcdN = foldr1 gcd
```

Then we can use as:

```haskell
gcdN [2, 4, 8, 12]
```

The output will be:

```haskell
2
```

Comment: Good point. One minor note, though: `0` is the identity for `gcd` (i.e. `gcd x 0 == gcd 0 x == x`), so a fully complete fold would look like `foldr gcd 0`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you already know how to find the GCD of two numbers, you can find the GCD of any amount of numbers:

```
gcd3 a b c = gcd a (gcd b c)

gcd4 a b c d = gcd a (gcd3 b c d)
-- Which is the same as
gcd4 a b c d = gcd a (gcd b (gcd c d))
```

And so on